# What set does this assembly with plastic foils come from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have this partial build, what set could it be from?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is from [76039-1: Ant-Man Final Battle](https://brickset.com/sets/76039-1/Ant-Man-Final-Battle)

[image]